# How can one put information within a signal waveform and make it to traverse through different kind of medium?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals

This is a soft question. There are different types of signals
like analog ,discrete or digital one.

But my question is how can one put information within a signal waveform and make it to traverse through different kind of physical medium, electronic circuits,devices etc?

Moreover ,in physics,we have Newtons laws for conservation of mass and energy . Now,is there any similar law in case of **signals**?

Comment: Signal carries the information - as simple as that.

Comment: @jojek sorry sir but as you can see in [link1][http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281856/why-is-a-geometric-progression-called-so] and [link2] [http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/199676/what-are-imaginary-numbers] they have detailed answers for basic questions but here I get only one line answer

Comment: It's not an answer - it's a comment.

Comment: Are you not happy with [this information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28electrical_engineering%29)? If not, you should consider asking a more specific question.

Comment: @Matt L. sir,actually I am not interested in definition of **signal** as given in wikipedia page. I wanted to understand with any sort of practical approach .

Comment: Have you read what it says at the link? Look at the introduction.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you want is [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory). Information can be quantified by [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). An analog signal channel always has some level of noise which limits the rate of information that can be sent through it. That limit is called the [Shannon limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem), or more specifically for a given channel bandwidth the [Shannon–Hartley theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Signal carries information by mapping.One way is in terms of binary.Assume signal with 100KHz as 0 bit and 200KHz as bit 1.So if you detect the frequencies of the signal the you would get the required bit stream from the sender.More specifically assume the signal is sent for 1s steps.You get a signal for 10s and you divide it into 10 signals of 1s each you take the spectrum and see the frequency based on this you get a 10 bit information.This example is similar to Frequency Shift Keying(FSK).There can be other ways  by using other parameters of the signal like amplitude,phase etc.